# COINCIDENCIAS EN FICHEROS ORDENADOS

Tags: c

estoy implementando un programa que se encargue de buscar en un fichero de datos una clave de búsqueda solicitada y me devuelva si ese fichero tiene o no la clave. La cosa es que al implementar el programa, me dice que la clave no está ahí, cuando en verdad si lo está.
Adjunto el código y el fichero a continuación:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdbool.h>

typedef struct{

    int CLAVE;
    
} REGISTRO;

bool buscar_uno_ordenado(const char *NOMBRE_F, int X, REGISTRO *REG_BUSCADO)
{

    bool ACABAR; 
    REGISTRO REG;
    
    FILE *F = fopen(NOMBRE_F, "r");
    
    if (F == NULL)
    {
    
        printf("EL ARCHIVO SOLICITADO NO EXISTE \n");
        return false;
    
    }
    
    ACABAR = false;
    
    while(( ACABAR == false )&&( !feof(F) ))
    {
    
        fread(&REG, sizeof(REGISTRO), 1, F);
        
        if( REG.CLAVE >= X )
        {
        
            ACABAR = true;
        
        }
    
    }
    
    if( ACABAR == true )
    {
    
        if(REG.CLAVE == X)
        {
        
            *REG_BUSCADO = REG;
        
        }
        else
        {
        
            ACABAR = false;
        
        }
    
    }
    
    fclose(F);
    
    return ACABAR;
}

int main()
{

    REGISTRO REG_BUSCADO;
    const char *nombre_archivo = "archivo2.dat";
    int clave_busqueda = 68;
    
    if(buscar_uno_ordenado(nombre_archivo, clave_busqueda, &REG_BUSCADO))
    {
    
        printf("EL REGISTRO HA SIDO ENCONTRADO. LA CLAVE ES: %d\n", REG_BUSCADO.CLAVE);
    
    }
    else
    {
    
        printf("EL REGISTRO SOLICITADO NO EXISTE \n");
    
    }       

    return 0;
}
```

---

### 1
2
3
4
12
14
23
24
29
45
54
67
68
96
162

Pues hasta ahí fue la cosa, he intentado con otras claves, incluso rehaciendo el programa, pero el programa siempre me demuestra que la clave no existe aunque en verdad si lo sea.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El código está bien si generas el archivo con `fwrite(&REG, sizeof(REGISTRO), 1, F)` o con un editor binario/hexadecimal como corresponde.

`fread` y `fwrite` trabajan con bytes. Por ejemplo, si 68 es un entero de 32 bits, sus bytes serían 68 0 0 0 en una computadora little endian.

Si en lugar de eso estás creando el archivo con un editor de texto, es un error leerlos con `fread`.

---

Para trabajar con texto existen las funciones `fscanf` y `fprintf`. Funcionan igual a `scanf` y `printf` solo que trabajan con archivos.

En este caso la manera correcta de generar el archivo es con un editor de texto o `fprintf("%i ", entero, archivo)`.

Entonces para recuperar la información tu código se vería así:

```
while(( ACABAR == false )&&( !feof(F) ))
{
    fscanf("%i", &REG.CLAVE, F);
    
    if( REG.CLAVE >= X )
    {
    
        ACABAR = true;
    
    }

}
```